# How to check whether demolition brick is safe to use?

Tags: walls, brick, demolition, chemicals

I would like to reuse demolition brick from building that was part of chemical factory. Factory was closed about 10 years ago, I know that sulphides and acids were heavily used there. I wonder if it's safe to use such brick or is there any way to verify? I plan to use it as root cellar elevation.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to send samples to a chemical analysis laboratory to get a more definitive answer, but the brick was likely never in direct contact with the chemicals and after 10 years I would expect they off gassed anything they might have picked up. If you don’t  notice an unusual smell from them, they are probably fine.

Comment: Besides the brick when exposed to any acids of any sort over a long time would have deteriorated a great deal on one side. This would be easily recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to talk to government offices and have a conversation about site assessments and EPA cleanup.  Presumably if they were able to sell the property, there would have been a level 2 site assessment.  The new owner would have been able to clean up the property to develop it.

I would ask your local government for that paperwork, and look at what exactly needed to be remediated.

The question is whether these bricks were salvaged a) *after* the EPA cleanup, or b) *as part of* the EPA cleanup, and thieves intercepted them out of the hazwaste stream.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "brick" and by "chemical". It is common for a chemical plant to use various chemical resistant types of brick in a factory area. Chosen to resist whatever chemical is possible in a spill. A company I worked for used acetic acid so had acid resistant brick that was essentially unaffected by acids. That brick could have been rinsed off and used in any home construction ;However I don't believe it came in the same sizes as domestic brick. "Sulfides" would be very unlikely to structurally affect common domestic fired brick but and residual could easily be a health concern .